# Is it possible to re-use a query plan from the plan cache from one database in another database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, optimization, execution-plan

For example, if I hit the sys dynamic views to select a specific query plan, am I able to insert that query plan into another database's plan cache, that runs the same exact query? (I know the query is hashed and compared to determine when to generate a new plan, so in my example I would ensure the query truly is exactly the same character by character.)

Comment: Good question, I am pretty sure this is impossible, but I look forwarding to reading the answers.

Comment: have you tried using plan guide ?

Comment: @KinShah What's plan guide?

Comment: @J.D. - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/plan-guides?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem. What do you hope to achieve if you were able to copy the plan?

Comment: Why do you want to reuse the plan in another database? In another database a different plan may be a better choise

Comment: @mustaccio I have a dynamic SQL script that needs to be executed across 600 databases. It runs in under one second (usually almost instantaneously) after the query plan is generated and added to the plan cache, but the initial run takes 10 to 15 seconds to generate the plan. So it would be nice if I can just generate the plan once and re-use it across the 599 other databases the query will run on. :)

Comment: @KinShah That's interesting, but I'm not sure how I could apply it here?

Comment: I think you would be better off sorting out why your query plan takes 10-15 seconds to be created/compiled. A query plan that's good in one of your databases may be terrible in another because of a different distribution of data in the table(s).

Comment: @alroc Yes, that's a fair point, but in my case the similarities between each database is sufficient such that the same plan should be used for each of them. The tables I'm querying are structured exactly the same, and the data is similar enough for the simplistic operation I'm doing such that I'd like to use the same plan for each database for this query. I understand my particular case is not common.

Comment: Thanks Paul White for putting bounty on this question! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## No

Ok, so that's the answer to your question, but you probably want to know *why*.

### Ok, so why not?

Different databases might have different data, and thus need different plans.

Say you restore the `WideWorldImporters` database to the same server ***TWICE*** (Let's call it `WWI_1` and `WWI_2`). You've got two identical databases. SQL Server could possibly create one plan and use it in queries for both databases.

But the problem is, the instant these two databases come online, thier "sameness" forks. They can be altered independently. Even if they maintain the same schema, their *data* can change independently. Thus, SQL Server **must** consider the databases independently when compiling plans. `WWI_1` could have different [statistics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/sql-server-statistics-basics/) from `WWI_2`, which could result in different plans. In order for SQL Server to use the same plan for both databases, SQL Server would need to keep track of the differences after forking--which would be more complicated & more expensive than just compiling/maintaining separate plans.

#### Let's take a real-world example

Let's pretend you are a software company, and host software for your customers. Every customer gets their own database. In your hosting environment, you might have hundreds of databases on every server, where every database has identical schema, but data unique to each client.

One client has a customer base with *95% California clients*. Querying the address table for all customers in California would result in a table *scan*.

```
-- For CustomerA this query returns 95% of the table, so it scans
SELECT CustomerID
FROM dbo.Addresses
WHERE StateCode = 'CA';
```

A different client has a customer base that is evenly distributed across every US state, and has a significant international business as well. A comparatively small percentage of clients are from California. In this case, querying the address table for all customers in California would result in a table *seek*.

```
-- For CustomerB this query returns <1% of the table, so it seeks
SELECT CustomerID
FROM dbo.Addresses
WHERE StateCode = 'CA';
```

Identical queries, on databases with identical schema, with radically different plans due to different statistics. Even if these two databases were both originally restored from the same source backup, SQL Server will need to compile separate plans.

It's not enough that the two queries are 100% identical, and the schema is 100% identical. A reused plan based only on those criteria could be very wrong--and thus SQL Server won't do it.

### Could you do it if you really wanted to?

Uh....kind of.

Let's use the same "you are a software company, and host software for your customers" example. You want to **force** the same plan across every hosted database, regardless of what SQL Server wants to do. You could use a [plan guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/plan-guides?view=sql-server-ver15) and apply the same guidance to every single database on the server. This isn't *quite* the same as "insert [one] query plan into another database's plan cache"... but it would be virtually the same thing.

### What about a totally trivial plan?

Something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.SomeTable` would be simple enough to use the same plan on both two databases, right? No, not even then!

Let's create an example:

- Create a sample database
- Create a table & populate it with some data

  - Note the table has a Clustered PK & a non-clustered index
- Backup & restore a second copy to the same server

Here's some code to do that:

```
CREATE DATABASE Sample1;
GO

USE Sample1
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (
    SomeID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    StuffType int,
    OtherStuff varchar(100),
    INDEX OtherStuff(OtherStuff)
);
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (StuffType,OtherStuff)
SELECT  object_id%50,
        name 
FROM sys.objects;
GO 1000


BACKUP DATABASE Sample1 TO DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/data/Sample1.bak' WITH INIT;


RESTORE DATABASE Sample2 FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/data/Sample1.bak'
    WITH MOVE 'Sample1' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/Sample2.mdf',
         MOVE 'Sample1_log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/Sample2_log.ldf';
```

Now, let's do that `COUNT(*)` query. Same plan on both? Yes! On my laptop, it's performing the count by scanning the clustered PK
[image: QueryPlansScanningPK]

SQL Server is choosing to scan the PK because it's smaller. The non-clustered index is larger because it's highly fragmented.

Now index maintenance happens on the `Sample1` database (but not `Sample2`). Someone rebuilds the indexes on `dbo.SomeTable`:

```
ALTER INDEX ALL ON Sample1.dbo.SomeTable REBUILD;
```

How does that affect the query plan?
[image: QueryPlansScanningDifferentIndexes]

On `Sample1`, the non-clustered index is now nice & compact. It is smaller than the PK. Scanning the non-clustered index will be the right choice on `Sample1 because it's smaller, fewer IOs, and will be faster.

On `Sample2`, scanning the PK is the right choice, because it's smaller, fewer IOs, and thus faster.

Identical schemas with identical data, with the second forked from a recent backup of the first. Both of these queries have different execution plans, but both also have the *best* query plan for their scenario.

Comment: All fair points. In my case because of the type of query I'm executing and the similarity in the data between my databases, it would probably make sense to use the same plan. Though I would wonder, are there not certain queries that would execute under the same plan regardless of the underlying data, for example SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE? Perhaps a global plan cache (server-wide) would be useful in certain instances?

Comment: @J.D. I added a section to my answer showing a detailed example of when `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.table;` can result in different plans on different databases with identical schemas & identical data. Even though the queries are different, SQL Server has picked the best-performing plan.

Comment: I must say, it's thoroughly refreshing to come back and re-read this answer retrospectively, now being more intimately familiar on the *how* and *why* SQL Server is designed the way it is. This was a very informative and well written answer. Thank you for it!